# how to bind 2 functions to a single event

Tags: python, wxpython

I have this bind "self.Bind(wx.EVT_LISTBOX, self.selLoadFile, listbox)". How would I add another function, I guess thats what youd call it. Like the self.selLoadFile, how would I add another function to the same event? I am making a music player and want the file to automatically play after it is selected. The self.selLoadFile function loads the file, how would I add the "self.Play" function to the same evt?

Thanks in advance!!

I'm sorry, I am new to programming. Could you help me out alittle? So if my functions where:

```
def selLoadFile(self, event):
        my_selection = self.myListBox.GetStringSelection()
        file_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"songs",my_selection)
        self.doLoadFile2(file_path)

def doLoadFile2(self, file_path):
    if not self.mc.Load(file_path):
        wx.MessageBox("Unable to load %s: Unsupported format?" % file_path, "ERROR", wx.ICON_ERROR | wx.OK)

    else:
        folder, filename = os.path.split(file_path)
        self.st_file.SetLabel('%s' % filename)
        self.mc.SetBestFittingSize()
        self.mc.Play()

def Play(self, event):
    self.mc.Play()
    self.playbackSlider.SetRange(0,self.mc.Length())
```

How would I include all 3 of the above functions in one function?

Comment: Haven't you already strung all these together?  Looks like selLoadFile() ends up calling doLoadFile2, which in turn will call Play()?

Comment: exactly, so I am not sure why it wont work

Comment: Are these within an object, or are these standalone functions?  A quick look suggests that the issues is going to be with calls that are self.function(), and self.mc.function(), suggesting you're dealing in two separate namespaces.  Also, if the issue is that you're experiencing an error, it'd be useful if you explained what behavior you're seeing.  Thanks!

Comment: self.mc is referring to the mediactrl, as you can see here: self.mc = wx.media.MediaCtrl(self)

Comment: so instead of self.mc.Play(), I think it should be self.Play()?  You still haven't explained what behavior you're seeing?

Comment: the wx.MediaCtrl() has a function by itself called Play(), my Play() function is a reaction to a button click. I am not getting any errors. I am just trying to figure out how to play the song after it is selected

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14316/discussion-between-worm-and-ernie)

Answer (score 6):

If you want to bind a widget to two event handlers, then just do it. That will work as long as you call [event.Skip()](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Event-class.html#Skip) at the end of the handler code. Without this line the event will be consumed by the first handler and will not be caught by any additional handlers. Here's a silly example:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class MyPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        btn = wx.Button(self, label="Press Me")
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.HandlerOne)
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.HandlerTwo)

    def HandlerOne(self, event):
        print "handler one fired!"
        event.Skip()

    def HandlerTwo(self, event):
        print "handler two fired!"
        event.Skip()

########################################################################
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Test")
        panel = MyPanel(self)
        self.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Out of curiousity, if one binds multiple handlers to the same event will the handlers fire in a predictable order or is it random? (Note: even if the handler order is predictable, if your handlers have any dependencies on each other then it's much much better to explicitly call subsequent methods. At the very least it makes your code more readable and easier to understand.)

Comment: I think they fire in order of last bound because when I run this, the second handler fires first. Personally, I usually do as you suggest and create a general method that my event handlers can call.